# How to Decipher Lego Building Instructions Filenames?

Tags: instructions

On the [official site for downloading lego instructions](http://service.lego.com/en-us/buildinginstructions), the filenames are often quite cryptic, and many sets have as many as six different files you can download and sometimes it's hard to tell which one you want. Can anyone enumerate what all those various part of the filename mean?

Examples 1:

```
Woody's Roundup! 7594

BI 3005/48 - - Download size: 5.71 Mb
BI 3005/48 - - Download size: 5.71 Mb
BI 3005/48 - 7594 V 110 2/2 - Download size: 5.94 Mb
BI 3005/60 - 7594 V 110 1/2 - Download size: 5.91 Mb
BI 3005/60 - 7594 V 140 1/2 - Download size: 5.91 Mb
BI 3005/60 - 7594 V 29 1/2 - Download size: 5.87 Mb
BI 3005/60 - 7594 V 39 1/2 - Download size: 5.87 Mb
```

Here's what I've figured out so far
BI = building instructins
3005 = set number
48 or 60 = ??
7594 = ??
V = version
110, 140, etc = ??
29 = A4 paper
39 = US letter paper
1/2 and 2/2 = the booklet number

Example 2:

```
Batman™: Arkham Asylum Breakout 10937
 BI 3016/12-65G - Download size: 4.68 Mb
 BI 3016/12-65G - Download size: 4.68 Mb
 BI 3016/68+4*- - Download size: 12.79 Mb
 BI 3016/68+4*- - Download size: 12.79 Mb
 BI 3016/76+4*- - Download size: 15.96 Mb
 BI 3016/76+4*- - Download size: 15.96 Mb
 BI 3016/80+4/65+115g - Download size: 14.5 Mb
 BI 3016/80+4/65+115g - Download size: 14.5 Mb
```

Now this one's even crazier `68+4*` huh??
And it kind of looks like all the files are duplicated? Or is the second one possibly a newer or bugfixed version?

Comment: Apparently the number atfer the "/" (48,60...) seems to be the number of pages

Comment: Also, the page itself says:
Building instructions labeled "NA" or "V39" may be printed on US standard letter size paper (8½ in × 11 in, 215.9 mm × 279.4 mm).
Building instructions labeled "IN" or "V29" may be printed on EU standard A4 paper (210 mm × 297mm, 8.3 in × 11.7 in.)

Comment: Based on Jobarc's comment, it appears the numbers with plus signs between them after the slash, eg `68+4` (72) and `80+4` (84) are number of pages as well, though I'm not sure why in some cases they break out the numbers with an extra sheet (4 pages) separate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After emailing back and forth with LEGO, I think I have an acceptable answer:

Example:

```
BI 3005/48 - 7594 V 110 2/2 - Download size: 5.94 Mb
^   ^   ^      ^   ^     ^                   ^
1   2   3      4   5     6                   7
```

1. Stands for `Building Instructions`
2. A number for internal usage by different LEGO teams.

   - You'll see that many different sets share this number, and all the numbers are fairly close (generally in the early 3000's).  My guess is that it has something to do with whoever drafted and finalized the instruction manual.
3. This number shows the number of pages in the manual.

   - When the number is show `x+y`, that means `x` building pages, and `y` instructional pages (e.g. what to do with bricks, or what bags are needed).
4. This is the set number.
5. This number refers to the page format of the instruction manual.

   - V29 means ISO A4 paper format.
   - V39 means letter paper format.
   - Other Vs (like 110, 140, etc) are different file formats.  LEGO said "those are the types of versions throughout our country that we ship to".  I'm guessing that they are related to the official formats for the manuals that are included with the kits.
6. The booklet number:  `x/y` means `x` booklet number out of `y` booklets.
7. The file size of the instruction in megabytes (not megabits, as it would seem to imply).