# What do the V# codes represent in the LEGO shop?

Tags: lego-store

The online LEGO shop references products with a V# code at the end, like this:

[image: item description]

What is the meaning of this code?

Comment: Where abouts in the shop are you seeing those?

Comment: During the checkout and final page. Yeah, I just bought those :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's related to the instruction manual format - see the comments to [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2962/56).

So for example

- V39 may be printed on US standard letter size paper
- V29 may be printed on EU standard A4 paper

Comment: I have ordered some keychains that had V46 and V120 on the invoice, the Back to School pack is also V46.